# ShiftIN operation in java using cd4021b

Tags: java, arduino, raspberry-pi, microcontroller

I am trying to do the shiftin operation using cd4021b with raspberry pi b+, i tried surfing in google but i couldn't get the prompt answer for my question. The below is the code that i am trying to run in my raspberrypi. I am not getting the shiftin output to the switchVar1 variable it always prints 0. Can anyone sort this problem?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        byte switchVar1;
        final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
        final GpioPinDigitalOutput latchPin = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_01, "MyLatch", PinState.HIGH);
        gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_04, "MyData");
        gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_06, "MyClock");        
        for(int n=0;n<=200;n++)
        {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            latchPin.high();
            Thread.sleep(20);
            latchPin.low(); 
            switchVar1 = Shift.shiftIn((byte) 4, (byte) 6, (byte)Shift.MSBFIRST);    
            System.out.println("switchVar1 " + switchVar1);
        }
 }
```